Pip installs not working (connection aborted)
So I was testing some pip installs and I recently got an error that looks like this:
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', UnknownProtocol('HTTP/2.0'))': /simple/googletrans/

(I used pip3 install googletrans just as an example) it does this for almost every pip function, and I have no clue what it means. 
Anyone have any insight?
Here is an exact copy and paste of my terminal command (using the example of pip3 install googletrans)
pip3 install googletrans
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', UnknownProtocol('HTTP/2.0'))': /simple/googletrans/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', UnknownProtocol('HTTP/2.0'))': /simple/googletrans/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', UnknownProtocol('HTTP/2.0'))': /simple/googletrans/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', UnknownProtocol('HTTP/2.0'))': /simple/googletrans/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', UnknownProtocol('HTTP/2.0'))': /simple/googletrans/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement googletrans (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for googletrans

I was expecting it to result in something with the loading bars for the downloads and all that, but it just dosent work.
Additional information,
I have tried doing this on a venv ve to no avail. 
My admin is working on it, but they are stuck too.
Im running VSCode on macOS;
python version 3.9 
pip version 24.2

May be due to your company proxy configuration.

Could also be a problem with your internet connection... Can you try another ISP?
